# Derivation of the Boltzmann factor using $\ln n!\sim n\ln n-n$

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

On this site (https://bouman.chem.georgetown.edu/S98/boltzmann/boltzmann.htm), the Boltzmann factor is derived using $\ln n!=n\ln n-n$ for $n\to\infty$, which means
$$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\ln n!}{n\ln n-n}=1. \tag*{(*)}$$
At some further stage, they take $\exp$ of both sides of some equation **based on** $(*)$ to approach the Boltzmann factor, but I doubt it can yield correct results, since $n!\ne e^{n\ln n-n}$ for $n\to\infty$, i.e.
$$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n!}{e^{n\ln n-n}}\ne 1.$$
Perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: Of course, but the asymptotic fails: It's true that $\ln n!\sim n\ln n-n$, but it's not true that $n!\sim e^{n\ln n-n}$. If you don't trust me: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+n+to+inf+n!%2Fe%5E(n+ln(n)-n) It's not $1$ anymore, it's $\infty$, so the asymptotic does not hold.

Comment: see [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)

Comment: I know Stirling's approximation. When finding the asymptotic for $n!$, the factor of $\sqrt{2\pi n}$ must be introduced. However, the asymptotic for $\ln n!$ is sufficient without the "$\pi$" factor. Put simply: one cannot always take $\exp$ of both sides of some asymptotic. My question is "how can the derivation be valid, then?"

Comment: Can you state what step in the derivation you are talking about? I don't see what you are talking about in the link.

Comment: @Aaron Stevens This: $\ln n_{i}=-\alpha -\beta\varepsilon _{i}\implies n_{i}=e^{-\alpha}e^{-\beta\varepsilon _{i}}$

Comment: That step isn't using any asymptotic form is it?

Comment: In fact, it is based on the asymptotic for $\ln n!$.

Comment: But they aren't taking exp of both sides of the asymptotic form there. They say that equation must be true and then do it. They aren't doing what you suggest

Comment: Perhaps this was causing my confusion. I still wasn't sure whether it's justified to take $\exp$ (where some $n$ is in the argument of $\ln$) because of the asymptotic.

Comment: You can also include the term $1/2n_i$ in the maximization and solve for $n_i$ leading to $$n_i = -\frac{1}{2{\rm W}\left(-{\rm e}^{\alpha + \beta \epsilon_i}/2\right)}$$ where W is the LambertW function. Since $n_i$ is large you can make use of $W(z) \approx z$ for small $z$ since $\alpha \rightarrow -\infty$.

Comment: @Diger Very interesting, this helped me out.